# Can't pass value in the function

Tags: android, flutter, function, dart

[quiz.dart snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/02Ri1.png)
[main.dart snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xFUZN.png)

I'm trying to pass score as int in the function but dunno why I can't do that.

Comment: What error you get?

Comment: please provide your quiz.dart code

Comment: @JohnJoe it's shown in the image under console

Comment: Please consider adding code snippets to your question/answer instead of their images. @FaseehHyder

Answer (score 0):

VoidCallback == void Function() but you are passing void Function(int) to this.
try replacing `VoidCallback` to `void Function(int)`

Answer (score 0):

Use  `final Function answerQuestion;` instead of  `final VoidCallback answerQuestion;`